# How much jQuery can the average computer handle without lagging?

Tags: jquery, performance

I ask this because I have a jQuery JavaScript file that's getting a tad long now. Also, what's the longest piece of jQuery anyone has ever seen/written?

Comment: Lines of code do not really translate to performance problems. Your biggest user-facing problems will likely come from a) slow AJAX calls, b) a **lot** of event handlers explicitly on elements (instead of using `delegate`, or c) poor algorithms looping through nested data structures repeatedly, e.g. _O(n^3)_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The performance of the jQuery code depends on its quality. For instance, these practices will improve performance:

- caching jQuery objects that are used multiple times, and/or in different handlers, e.g. `var $nav = $("#nav");`
- using native API in certain situations, e.g. `this.value` instead of `$(this).val()`, and `this.id` instead of `$(this).attr("id")`
- using delegation to avoid setting to many event handlers (and I don't mean the delegate() method), e.g. `$("#table").click(function(e) { var row = $(e.target).closest("tr")[0]; });` instead of `$("#table tr").click(function() { });`
- using native loops instead of `$.each()`
- using efficient selectors, e.g. ID selectors when available, `$("p.foo")` instead of `$(".foo")`
- etc.

There are dozens of good practices that improve jQuery performance. Applying these practices is important. The length of the code, not so much.

Comment: is `this` and `$(this)` interchangeable when referring to, for example, the element that has just been clicked? I'll experiment...

Comment: Also, thank you for your concise, very helpful answer! +1

Comment: @Jam No, those two are not equal. Inside the click handler, `this` refers to the DOM element, whereas `$(this)` is a jQuery object that contains that DOM element. Such a jQuery object is necessary when you want to execute jQuery methods on the DOM element.

Comment: Thanks. Just what I needed to know :-)

Answer (score 2):

This is much more dependent on how you write your code, HTML, CSS & JS, and how you configure your server to serve it up.

- Make sure you turn gzip on for your *.html, *.css, *.js (text based files) from your server
- Make sure you set a far-future expiry on your static content (images, etc.)
- Version your CSS/JS files so that you can set a far-future expiry on them to optimize the end-user caching
- Put your JS in the external files, not inline in you HTML as it can't be cached there
- Verify your jQuery/JavaScript code is as optimized as it can be... no extra redundant loops etc.
- Avoid deeply nested tables, or lots of iframes... they hurt your performance.
- In your AJAX calls, if you can... return JSON vs. XML
- Move as much styling as you can into external CSS files, again, this will allow for both caching, and effective re-use

That all said, if you have some sample code we can look at we can give you some better tips.

For example, if you had a `<select>` element (drop down) with 1500 `<option>` elements in it you might have jQuery like this to get the currently selected value:

```
var foo = $('#mySelectID > option:selected').attr('value');
```

Due to the way the jQuery selector is parsed and processed, this may take a long time to find the actual selected option and retrieve its value.  On the other hand, this code may run much, much faster.

```
var foo = document.getElementById('mySelectID').value;
```

If you have a code sample, it will help us tremendously in providing the most appropriate advice. ;-)

Comment: I don't have a specific code example - I was mainly looking for tips and good practice. I'd love to see 1500 option elements on a page :-P
Thanks very much for your excellent answer - you make good points and I shall bear these in mind when developing jQuery stuff! +1